# GenX on ubuntu software

Tags: goldendict

I wants to download the GenX reflectivity software on my ubuntu 14.04 os, ubuntu software centre is not showing this program. can any body help me.

Comment: http://genx.sourceforge.net/install.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Install some dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-appdirs 
   sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 
   sudo apt-get install python-h5py
   ```
2. Download the Linux source package [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genx/)
3. Extract the archive

   ```
   sudo unzip ~/Downloads/GenX-2.4.2-source.zip -d /opt
   ```
4. Test the installation

   ```
   python /opt/genx/genx.py
   ```

   [image]
5. Set the executable bit

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /opt/genx/genx.py
   ```
6. Create a desktop file

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/genx.desktop &
   ```

   and add the content below.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=GenX
   Comment=GenX
   Type=Application
   Exec=/opt/genx/genx.py
   Icon=/opt/genx/debian_build/genx_128x128.png 
   Categories=
   Terminal=false
   StartupNotify=true
   ```
7. Save the file and close your editor
8. Start GenX from Dash/GNOME Shell

Maybe it is also possible to create a DEB papckage because we have a `debian_build` folder,
but for me ... this method did not work.